# Does posting anonymously violate a site suspension or ban?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, rules

Pretty straightforward question, but some of the mods I've asked have been unsure of the answer.

I know posting with a sockpuppet account *does* violate the rules of a site suspension, but what about anonymous posts?

If you log out of a network site you're suspended/banned from and post a question anonymously, is it considered 'ban dodging'?  Obviously any rep generated from votes won't be linked to your account, but it's still not very clear whether or not this is a rule violation.

Comment: How is this different from a sockpuppet? Anonymous `user####` accounts are still technically accounts.

Comment: @Asad That's exactly what I'd like to know.  You can't gain rep from anonymous accounts, right?

Comment: As an aside: on Stack Overflow you cannot ask questions anonymously. On (all?) other sites you can. Do other sites even have automatic bans?

Comment: [physics.se] has had problems with the past regarding users who use unregistered accounts to get past a suspension. We generally destroy (delete user _and_ posts) these socks unless some of their posts have some worth.

Answer (score 11):

You are circumventing the suspension, no matter if you are using an unregistered guest account or create a new registered one. I don't see how the type of account would make a difference. Unregistered accounts are not that much different from regular accounts.

So I would say that this certainly constitutes a circumvention of the suspension and would have the usual consequences (removal/merge/suspension of the new account and a longer suspension on the main account).

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm a moderator on Skeptics and Biology</sub>

Comment: Just curious, since you're a moderator and might know: do those sites also have *automatic* post bans?

Comment: Automatic question bans are only on SO, SU, SF and Programmers, I think. Automatic answer bans are on all sites, but they are pretty hard to hit.

Comment: I didn't realize 'bans' and 'suspensions' were different things.  Presumably the 'rule' is the same in either situation?